# PLM object to LaTeX table

Tags: r, plm

How can I make LaTeX tables with plm objects?

I have been using apsrtable to make LaTeX tables for output summaries for lm objects, but can't seem to find an easy way to do the same with plm.  I am calculating panel corrected standard errors using plm and VcovBK(), but then have to go into latex and change the standard errors by hand.

Comment: Dunno if you have seen this estout package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/estout/estout.pdf

Comment: Reproducible example with data and code (what you already tried) will be great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach which shouod work is to put your results in a `data.frame` and use `xtable` to create a LaTex table. This might take a bit more work than using premade templates, but it is very flexible.

Comment: I tried this, but it said that a plm object cannot be coerced into a data.frame:Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class 'c("plm", "panelmodel")' into a data.frame

Comment: I meant taking the results from a plm object. Try and see what `attributes(plm_object)` returns, or `str(plm_object)`. In that way you can see what is part of the object, e.g. coefficients. Than you can manually extract them and place them into a `data.frame` for `xtable`.

Comment: In case this is helpful for anyone else, I figured out how to include PCSE (or any 'robust' standard errors) into apsrtable generated LaTex tables.  Once you have calculated the standard errors you would like you can simply add a vector of new standard errors to the original lm object.  The vector should have the name 'se' to be used automatically by apsrtable.  For instance,  lm1$se <- plm1[,2]. Where lm1 is the original lm object and plm1 is a matrix containing the vector of PCSEs.  For further info, see the apsrtable Implementation & Extension Guide

Answer (score 5):

As of version 2.0, the [stargazer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/index.html) package supports PLM objects.  It also makes some very nice tables, so it is worth a look.